# Elevated response times in NFC dialog on Android app

Tags: android, performance, nfc, hce

Hi to all the Community

I am experiencing an uncommon problem with a card emulation android app. When receiving an APDU from a card reader, the processCommandApdu() method extended from HostApduService gives a processing time of less than 1 ms (measured with System.nanotime(), but the processing time reported by the host application / simulator adds about 30 ms to that time, so the APDU is processed by the host PC in about 30 ms.

The app is a very simple skeleton with just the minimum features and code as described by Google, and the response is hardcoded.

Does anyone have and idea of the possible reason for this behavior?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How is the processing time measured in the host application? Is this the processing time for just one APDU or does this include enumeration, selection and APDU transmission?

Comment: Hi, Michael. 
This time is for just one single APDU, not including power on, nor selection; to be precise, is an EMV READ RECORD APDU command
Many thanks